# Unity - TextAsset writing error in Real Device

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I created Shop system in Unity. After successfully awarded ad, I want to modify text asset for the selected ball. ( For example you open the ball by watching 3 videos). In unity editor text asset is modified but in the real device number of watching ad for the ball not decremented.

These are error I got :
[image]

And this is my code:

```
public override void DecrementGameItemCount(BallItem selectedBallItem,int decrementCount)
   {
     BallItems ballItems = JsonUtility.FromJson<BallItems>(textAsset.text);
    List<BallItem> ballItemList = new List<BallItem>();
    ballItemList.AddRange(ballItems.ballItems);

    BallItem ballItemFromJson = ballItemList.Find((item) => item.name == selectedBallItem.name);

    int index = Array.IndexOf(ballItems.ballItems, ballItemFromJson);
    selectedBallItem.count--;

    if(selectedBallItem.count==0){
        selectedBallItem.isPurchased = true;
    }
    string updatedBallItemToJson = JsonUtility.ToJson(selectedBallItem);


    JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(updatedBallItemToJson, ballItems.ballItems[index]);



    string path = Application.dataPath + "/Resources/Files/ball_list.json";
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
    {
        writer.Write(JsonUtility.ToJson(ballItems));
    }
}
```

Error is in this line :

```
  BallItems ballItems = JsonUtility.FromJson<BallItems>(textAsset.text);
```

And the error in text :

Error Unity Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function.

How can I solve this error ?

Comment: The real error is "`get_bytes` can be called only from the Main thread" (check the topmost line in your screenshot). Check this https://forum.unity.com/threads/can-only-be-called-from-the-main-thread.622948/#post-4183546

Comment: Also, `Application.dataPath` is read-only location you can not write a file there. Instead use `Application.persistentDataPath` to write file.